# Manually focus webcam from openCV

Tags: opencv

How can i set from openCV the focus of a webcam or any other camera? I would like to find the distance of on object, but I want to write the program, so I need to manually be able to focus, manually meaning from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set focus from opencv, but windows SDK allows it. Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567802(v=vs.85).aspx
I've used setting of minidriver properties for focus control, and it works perfect with logitch 905c and 920c.

I found the code example on my disk, hope it'll be userful:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * DirectShow Pan/Tilt/Zoom sample for Logitech QuickCam devices
 * 
 * Copyright 2007 (c) Logitech. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * This code and information is provided "as is" without warranty of
 * any kind, either expressed or implied, including but not limited to
 * the implied warranties of merchantability and/or fitness for a
 * particular purpose.
 *
 * Version: 1.1
 ****************************************************************************/

#include <dshow.h>
#include <Ks.h>             // Required by KsMedia.h
#include <KsMedia.h>        // For KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_*


struct ControlInfo {
    long min;
    long max;
    long step;
    long def;
    long flags;
};


/*
 * Print information about a control in an easily readable fashion.
 */
void print_control_info(ControlInfo *info)
{
    char flags[32] = "";

    if(info->flags & KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_AUTO)
    {
        strcat_s(flags, sizeof(flags), "AUTO | ");
    }
    else if(info->flags & KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL)
    {
        strcat_s(flags, sizeof(flags), "MANUAL | ");
    }

    if(info->flags & KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_RELATIVE)
    {
        strcat_s(flags, sizeof(flags), "RELATIVE");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat_s(flags, sizeof(flags), "ABSOLUTE");
    }

    printf(
        "        min:   %d\n"
        "        max:   %d\n"
        "        step:  %d\n"
        "        def:   %d\n"
        "        flags: 0x%08X (%s)\n",
        info->min, info->max, info->step, info->def, info->flags, flags
    );
}


/*
 * Pans the camera by a given angle.
 *
 * The angle is given in degrees, positive values are clockwise rotation (seen from the top),
 * negative values are counter-clockwise rotation. If the "Mirror horizontal" option is
 * enabled, the panning sense is reversed.
 */
HRESULT set_mechanical_pan_relative(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl, long value)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    long flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_RELATIVE | KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;

    hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Pan, value, flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set CameraControl_Pan property value to %d. (Error 0x%08X)\n", value, hr);

    // Note that we need to wait until the movement is complete, otherwise the next request will
    // fail with hr == 0x800700AA == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BUSY).
    Sleep(500);

    return hr;
}


/*
 * Tilts the camera by a given angle.
 *
 * The angle is given in degrees, positive values are downwards, negative values are upwards.
 * If the "Mirror vertical" option is enabled, the tilting sense is reversed.
 */
HRESULT set_mechanical_tilt_relative(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl, long value)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    long flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_RELATIVE | KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;

    hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Tilt, value, flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set CameraControl_Tilt property value to %d. (Error 0x%08X)\n", value, hr);

    // Note that we need to wait until the movement is complete, otherwise the next request will
    // fail with hr == 0x800700AA == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BUSY).
    Sleep(500);

    return hr;
}


/*
 * Resets the camera's pan/tilt position by moving into a corner and then back to the center.
 */
void reset_machanical_pan_tilt(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl)
{
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, 180);
    Sleep(500);
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, 180);
    Sleep(500);
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, -64);
    Sleep(500);
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, -24);
    Sleep(500);
}


/*
 * Sets the digital pan angle.
 *
 * Positive values pan to the right, negative values pan to the left. Note that the digital pan
 * angle only has an influence if the digital zoom is active.
 */
HRESULT set_digital_pan_absolute(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl, long value)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;

    // Specifying the KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE flag instructs the driver
    // to use digital instead of mechanical pan.
    long flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE | KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;

    hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Pan, value, flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set CameraControl_Pan property value to %d. (Error 0x%08X)\n", value, hr);

    return hr;
}


/*
 * Sets the digital tilt angle.
 *
 * Positive values tilt downwards, negative values tilt upwards. Note that the digital pan
 * angle only has an influence if the digital zoom is active.
 */
HRESULT set_digital_tilt_absolute(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl, long value)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;

    // Specifying the KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE flag instructs the driver
    // to use digital instead of mechanical tilt.
    long flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE | KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;

    hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Tilt, value, flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set CameraControl_Tilt property value to %d. (Error 0x%08X)\n", value, hr);

    return hr;
}


/*
 * Sets the digital zoom value.
 *
 * The minimum value is 50 and means no zoom (100%). The maximum value is 200
 * and means 4x zoom (400%).
 */
HRESULT set_digital_zoom_absolute(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl, long value)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    long flags = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE | KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_MANUAL;

    hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Zoom, value, flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set CameraControl_Zoom property value to %d. (Error 0x%08X)\n", value, hr);

    return hr;
}


/*
 * Resets the digital pan and tilt angles.
 */
void reset_digital_pan_tilt(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl)
{
    set_digital_pan_absolute(pCameraControl, 0);
    set_digital_tilt_absolute(pCameraControl, 0);
}


/*
 * Resets the digital zoom.
 */
void reset_digital_zoom(IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl)
{
    set_digital_zoom_absolute(pCameraControl, 50);
}


/*
 * Test a camera's pan/tilt properties
 *
 * See also:
 *
 * IAMCameraControl Interface
 *     http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783833.aspx
 * PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL
 *     http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa510754.aspx
 */
HRESULT test_pan_tilt(IBaseFilter *pBaseFilter)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl = NULL;
    ControlInfo panInfo = { 0 };
    ControlInfo tiltInfo = { 0 };
    ControlInfo zoomInfo = { 0 };
    long value = 0, flags = 0;

    printf("    Reading pan/tilt property information ...\n");

    // Get a pointer to the IAMCameraControl interface used to control the camera
    hr = pBaseFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IAMCameraControl, (void **)&pCameraControl);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to access IAMCameraControl interface.\n");
        return hr;
    }

    // Retrieve information about the pan and tilt controls
    hr = pCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Pan, &panInfo.min, &panInfo.max, &panInfo.step, &panInfo.def, &panInfo.flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to retrieve CameraControl_Pan property information.\n");
        return hr;
    }
    printf("      Pan control:\n");
    print_control_info(&panInfo);

    hr = pCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Tilt, &tiltInfo.min, &tiltInfo.max, &tiltInfo.step, &tiltInfo.def, &tiltInfo.flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to retrieve CameraControl_Tilt property information.\n");
        return hr;
    }
    printf("      Tilt control:\n");
    print_control_info(&tiltInfo);

    hr = pCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Zoom, &zoomInfo.min, &zoomInfo.max, &zoomInfo.step, &zoomInfo.def, &zoomInfo.flags);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to retrieve CameraControl_Zoom property information.\n");
        return hr;
    }
    printf("      Zoom control:\n");
    print_control_info(&zoomInfo);

    //*
    printf("    Resetting pan/tilt/zoom ...\n");
    reset_machanical_pan_tilt(pCameraControl);
    reset_digital_pan_tilt(pCameraControl);
    reset_digital_zoom(pCameraControl);
    Sleep(3000);
    //*/

    //*
    printf("    Testing mechanical pan ...\n");
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, 40);
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, 20);
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, -20);
    set_mechanical_pan_relative(pCameraControl, -40);
    Sleep(3000);
    //*/

    //*
    printf("    Testing mechanical tilt ...\n");
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, 20);
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, 10);
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, -10);
    set_mechanical_tilt_relative(pCameraControl, -20);
    Sleep(3000);
    //*/

    //*
    printf("    Testing digital pan/tilt/zoom ...\n");
    set_digital_zoom_absolute(pCameraControl, 100);     // Zoom to 200%
    Sleep(1000);

    set_digital_pan_absolute(pCameraControl, 40);
    Sleep(1000);
    set_digital_pan_absolute(pCameraControl, 80);
    Sleep(1000);

    set_digital_zoom_absolute(pCameraControl, 200);     // Zoom to 400%
    Sleep(1000);

    set_digital_tilt_absolute(pCameraControl, 40);
    Sleep(1000);
    set_digital_tilt_absolute(pCameraControl, 60);
    Sleep(1000);

    reset_digital_pan_tilt(pCameraControl);
    Sleep(1000);
    reset_digital_zoom(pCameraControl);
    Sleep(3000);
    //*/

    //*
    printf("    Testing digital zoom ...\n");
    for(int i = zoomInfo.min; i <= zoomInfo.max; i += zoomInfo.step)
    {
        set_digital_zoom_absolute(pCameraControl, i);
        Sleep(10);
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    for(int i = zoomInfo.max; i >= zoomInfo.min; i -= zoomInfo.step)
    {
        set_digital_zoom_absolute(pCameraControl, i);
        Sleep(10);
    }
    //*/

    return S_OK;
}


/*
 * Do something with the filter. In this sample we just test the pan/tilt properties.
 */
void process_filter(IBaseFilter *pBaseFilter)
{
    test_pan_tilt(pBaseFilter);
}


/*
 * Enumerate all video devices
 *
 * See also:
 *
 * Using the System Device Enumerator:
 *     http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms787871.aspx
 */
int enum_devices()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    printf("Enumerating video input devices ...\n");

    // Create the System Device Enumerator.
    ICreateDevEnum *pSysDevEnum = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void **)&pSysDevEnum);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to create system device enumerator.\n");
        return hr;
    }

    // Obtain a class enumerator for the video input device category.
    IEnumMoniker *pEnumCat = NULL;
    hr = pSysDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnumCat, 0);

    if(hr == S_OK) 
    {
        // Enumerate the monikers.
        IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
        ULONG cFetched;
        while(pEnumCat->Next(1, &pMoniker, &cFetched) == S_OK)
        {
            IPropertyBag *pPropBag;
            hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, 
                (void **)&pPropBag);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // To retrieve the filter's friendly name, do the following:
                VARIANT varName;
                VariantInit(&varName);
                hr = pPropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &varName, 0);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Display the name in your UI somehow.
                    wprintf(L"  Found device: %s\n", varName.bstrVal);
                }
                VariantClear(&varName);

                // To create an instance of the filter, do the following:
                IBaseFilter *pFilter;
                hr = pMoniker->BindToObject(NULL, NULL, IID_IBaseFilter,
                    (void**)&pFilter);

                process_filter(pFilter);

                //Remember to release pFilter later.
                pPropBag->Release();
            }
            pMoniker->Release();
        }
        pEnumCat->Release();
    }
    pSysDevEnum->Release();

    return 0;
}


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    int result;

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    result = enum_devices();

    CoUninitialize();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Logitech webcams (tested C525, C920 and C931e). The key `28` is for setting focus. Note that the focus value should be multiples of 5 (0, 5, 10... 255), otherwise the VideoCapture object would simply not respond.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

focus = 0  # min: 0, max: 255, increment:5
cam.set(28, focus)
```

Comment: It is better to use cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS instead of 28. Makes it much more cleaner and readable.

Comment: how is this possible if the other answer to the question says that you can't set focus from opencv? was the library updated or something?