# Set WebCamera focus with OpenCv in Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a logitech C920 Web camera.
I was able to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819965 to get the autofocus turned off and manually set the desired focus while I ran the python code on My Windows 10 pc. Also, I could see the changes in focus when adjusting value.
But when I tried to connect the same camera to Raspberry Pi (3 B+ ) and run the same code, for whatever the value of focus I set, it just doesn't respond. Same blurry images always.
What could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the driver and/or video backend used by `cv::VideoCapture`.

You can try setting the focus directly with `v4l2-ctl`:
https://www.christitus.com/logitech-c920-linux-driver/

Comment: It worked. This pointed me in the right direction and I further went on found a way to use it with Python. Subprocess function made it possible.